# Large UIImage causing low memory and crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have a large image that I load into a UIImageView. The image is a PNG and it's @2x file size is: 384K. The image is 5119x2413 pixels. The image can be zoomed by the user by using pinch gestures. The reason the image is so large is so that when the UIImageView is transformed by pinching the quality will stay the same.

The problem I'm having is that on some devices especially the latest iPod Touch it will crash while attempting to display this screen.

I've ran the app via Instruments and profiled it using the Leak/Allocations profiles. The app's live bytes generally hovers around 4MB when using the app, but as soon as you view the screen containing the UIImageView this shoots up to 40MB! Onces the image is on the screen the memory returns to around 4MB.

The problem I'm having is that more times than not on older devices and ones limited by memory like the iPod Touch my app is being terminated by the system, along with some system services like SpringBoard.

I've tried using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` instead of `[UIImage imageNamed:]` to load the image as I am aware that `[UIImage imageNamed:]` caches the image but this has had no effect.

It seems that the spike in live memory caused when attempting to display the image for the first time is causing a low memory situation and the app is being terminated by the OS.

I'm curious to how I can fix this, and how Apple are dealing with loading large images in the Photos app.

Just for the record I'm using ARC and iOS 5.1.1 with XCode 4.4.1.

[image]

Comment: Please see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011173). I have done this example and it worked awesomely.

Comment: try Tiling the image, try sample code [a PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)! from WWDC 2010, it will help.